# When I use var_dump, nothing returns. I am trying to make sure that I fully connected to my Mongo database

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I have created a database called an "example" and a collection called "cars", which have inserted data into. When I run the var_dump, I get nothing. Is there something wrong with my connection ? Or is it something else

```
<?php
$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->example->cars;

$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ( $cursor as $id => $value )
{
    echo "$id: ";
    var_dump( $value );
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean for _nothing_? What's the exact output?

Comment: I think your code doesn't go into loop, so $cursor is empty array

Comment: Nothing there isn't an output ?